# C# console string padding with unicode characters

Tags: c#, string, unicode, console-application

I am using `Console` class to print some results which sometimes contain Unicode characters. The traditional padding method of using `String.PadRight` does not work properly because some Unicode characters occupy one char in string but two char on screen. Here is the code:

```
        Console.Out.WriteLine("123".PadRight(10, '-'));
        Console.Out.WriteLine("xxxxxx".PadRight(10, '-'));
        Console.Out.WriteLine("你好".PadRight(10, '-'));
```

In the output, the first two lines end at the same position while the third one are two characters longer. The code page is: 936 (ANSI/OEM - 简体中文 GBK).

So I would like to know whether there is a way to get the real width of a string when it is printed to the console screen. Thanks!

Comment: Can you write the code without using the actual characters, use `\u0000` format instead, here in the question I mean?

Comment: That’s a font problem, there is really nothing you can do about that if you don’t have knowledge (and control) about the font that is used for those characters (which you don’t in a console).

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Here I only want to show what the code will do. Of course I will avoid writing this kind of things directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do your padding *after* output by checking the current cursor position, something like:

```
private static void WriteConsolePadded(string value, int length, char padValue)
{
    Console.Write(value);
    if (Console.CursorLeft < length)
    {
        Console.Write(new string(padValue, length - Console.CursorLeft));
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

(Except, obviously, put a *lot* more thought into better naming for the method and arguments)

And then you'd have:

```
WriteConsolePadded("123",10, '-');
WriteConsolePadded("xxxxxx",10, '-');
WriteConsolePadded("你好",10, '-');
```

(Other variants may also make sense, such as measuring the start position before output, rather than just assuming it's always at the left most position)

Comment: This is exactly what I want. Thank you so much!